# bundle exec rake assets:precompile issue with the generated files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, web-deployment, phusion

I could successfully host the fulcrum app on phusion but I am going nuts with some configuration issues.

1) For some reason there are no assets in the public folder but if I generate them using rake they have the weird digest attached to the suffix and the app says can't find file if I dont rename them like logo-30879aa42d1b343434a40fda1b11734b.png to logo.png

2) I renamed the assets and now the js files are not picking the root of the url i.e. http://example.com/fulcrum/assets/logo-30879aa42d1b343434a40fda1b11734b.png should be the url but the url is being set as http://example.com/assets/logo-30879aa42d1b343434a40fda1b11734b.png (missing root)

Could anyone kindly point out my configuration mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem was in my production.rb

config.action_controller.asset_host was causing the trouble